# can't combine script and php div.innerHTML += "<form action='\"{{route('stock.store')}}\"' method='post'>@csrf</form>";

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a button that calls a script method named add_Fields(). I used .innerHTML to add fields in a form.

The problem is when i put the attribute action with a value of {{route('stock.store')}} the whole script code doesn't work.

Can anybody help me with this?

```js
 var i = 0;
    var d = document.getElementById("content");
d.innerHTML += "<div class='form-group row'>"+
                "<span class='col-md-2'>UNIT:<input form='form"+i+"' id='unit' type='text' name='unit' class='form-control' required></span>"+
                "<span class='col-md-2'>QTY:<input form='form"+i+"' id='quantity' type='number' name='quantity' class='form-control' required></span>"+
                "<span class='col-md-4'>UNIT COST:<input form='form"+i+"' id='unit_cost' type='number' name='unit_cost' class='form-control' required></span>"+
                "<span class='col-md-4'>AMOUNT:<input form='form"+i+"' id='unit_cost' type='number' name='unit_cost' class='form-control' required></span>"+
            "</div>"+
            "<form id='form"+i+"' action='\"{{route('stock.store')}}\"' method='post'>@csrf</form>"+
            "";
```

Answer (score 2):

replace below code for form tag and make sure the route is defined in routes\web.php file

```
"<form id='form"+i+"' action='{{route('stock.store')}}' method='post'>@csrf</form>"+
```

Comment: the route was defined. but the source code i showed is in a script tag

Comment: @RexZednelab, remove \" from the variable, it will work. if you get any error on screen, share that screenshot here